# UWP different navigation behaviour in phone and desktop/laptop

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

In my UWP application I have 2 frames. In the default frame, I have a `SplitView`
and in `SplitView.Content`, I have a custom frame called `Mainframe`. My app has around 5 page and all of them are loaded in `MainFrame`. `MainPage` is the only page that is in the default frame.  This is the code I use for navigation:

```
 public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();            
    MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageX));
    MainFrame.Navigated += MainFrame_Navigated;     
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
}

private void MainFrame_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
        ((Frame)sender).CanGoBack ?
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible :
        AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Collapsed;
}

private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MainFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(PageX))
    {
        MainFrame.BackStack.Clear();
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageY));               
    }
    else if (MainFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        MainFrame.GoBack();
    }
}
```

This works as expected on a desktop ( that is, when I am on pageX and click the back button, I am taken to pageY ) but on a phone it works as expected for most parts except when I click the back button from pageX, if that is the case, the app just exits. But during debugging I found out that I am first taken to pageY an then the app closes ( It just happens very fast ). But it does not get completely closed, it gets minimized and when I again open the app, it will be on pageY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `e.Handled` when you navigate forward.

```
private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    if(MainFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(PageX))
    {
        MainFrame.BackStack.Clear();
        MainFrame.Navigate(typeof(PageY));               
    }
    else if (MainFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        MainFrame.GoBack();
    }
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

When you navigate to PageY you are saying that you did not handle the back button which means the application (framework) will handle the button and the default behavior for the back button on Windows Mobile is to exit the app